# Edit box: disable user formatting, but add my own

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I know that rich text boxes in HTML is a bit of a minefield, but I'm hoping this particular situation won't be too tricky. I want a text box which the user can't format, but through scripting I can have it add some light formatting to (so a textarea won't work).

My first thought was that I could use a `contentEditable`, and if the user doesn't have a toolbar, they can't do much, but there's still the Ctrl + B, Ctrl + I, etc combinations. So I did this:

```
ctrlHandler = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
};

this.keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
        $(this).bind('keypress', ctrlHandler);
    }
});
this.keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
        $(this).unbind('keypress', ctrlHandler);
    }
});
```

So when the Ctrl key is pressed (`keydown`) an event handler is bound to keypress which prevents the default and when it's released the event handler is unbound. Clever, eh? (I'd work out how to handle cut/copy/paste etc combinations later.) With this, the event handler gets bound correctly, but `event.preventDefault()` doesn't actually prevent the default! The text gets made bold/italic/underlined exactly as if I'd done nothing. The formatting change seems to happen before the event fires. Using `keydown` or `keyup` instead of `keypress` doesn't work either. Can anyone think of another (cross browser) approach, or how to make this one work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! It seems I've misunderstood what `event.ctrlKey` does. Pressing Ctrl + B doesn't fire two keydown events... it fires one with event.ctrlKey set to true. So `if (event.ctrlKey) event.preventDefault()` will do the trick. Not yet tested in all browsers.